# Issue with vlookup and absolute reference and lastrow VBA

Tags: arrays, excel, vba, vlookup

[image]I have a macro which performs a vlookup by taking the vendor name in column J and looks for the vendor number in my table array of my vlookup in column C and D.   However when I run the macro, something goes visibly wrong with my vlookup. Please see the formula inside the picture attached.  Apparently, the part of my table array in my vlookup does not work properly. Actually, I would like that my vlookup returns me a fixed table array (I mean with absolute reference and dollar) from point of origin C5 and as limit point the last row in column D (I mean the limit of my table array should be the last row of column D).

Please see my VBA code below, it seems that this part of my VBA code inside my vlookup is wrong
: C4" & LastRow & "

Thanks a lot for your help.
Xavi

```
Sub insertvlookuptogetmyvendornumber()
Dim LastRow As Integer
LastRow = Range("D" & Rows.Count).End(xlUp).Row
PenultimateLastRow = Range("J" & Rows.Count).End(xlUp).Offset(-1, 0).Row 

Range("I4").Select
ActiveCell.FormulaR1C1 = "Vendor number"
Range("I5").Select
ActiveCell.FormulaR1C1 = "=VLOOKUP(RC[1],R5C3:C4" & LastRow & ",2,0)"
Selection.AutoFill Destination:=Range("I5:I" & PenultimateLastRow), Type:=xlFillDefault
End Sub
```

Comment: Is the list of vendor names finite? If so, why use VBA at all? Failing that you can maintain a lookup table and simply add storing your  historic table into a dictionary, then looping those two columns of the pivottable table adding items to the dictionary if the key doesn't exist. Then write the dictionary back out to the historic table area.

Comment: Thank you very much QHarr for your Reply, in fact on the Picture I attached, I only made a screenshot of a Little part of the vendor Name and vendor number, in reality the list is much more longer... Moreover, I tried to automate it in VBA because this is something at work I have to do on a regular basis, unfortunately my macro does not work due to my wrong vlookup...

Answer (score 1, accepted):

As per my comment I would maintain a historic table of names and numbers. I would initially read this into a dictionary and then loop the appropriate columns of the pivottable updating the dictionary value if the name exists. If the name doesn't exist then add the name and number to the dictionary. At the end write it all back out the historic table.

The historic table is your current table where you are trying to do VLookup. In this case, that table would only contain matched pairs which have new values added to it from pivottable, or existing values updated.

To re-iterate, your table on the right, columns I & J should only have matched pairs in it to start with. Hardcoded.

This assumes no subtotal/total rows within pivottable body, though these can be excluded, if present, with an update to the code.

```
Option Explicit

Public Sub UpdateReferenceTable()

    Dim lastRow As Long, dict As Object, ws As Worksheet, pvt As PivotTable, i As Long
    Set ws = ThisWorkbook.Worksheets("Sheet1")
    Set pvt = ws.PivotTables("PivotTable1")

    Set dict = CreateObject("Scripting.Dictionary")

    With ws
        lastRow = .Cells(.Rows.Count, "I").End(xlUp).Row
    End With

    Dim initialDictData(), pivotTableUpdates()
    initialDictData = ws.Range("I9:J" & lastRow).Value

    For i = LBound(initialDictData, 1) To UBound(initialDictData, 1)
        dict(initialDictData(i, 2)) = initialDictData(i, 1)
    Next

    Dim names(), vendorNumbers()
    names = Application.Transpose(pvt.PivotFields("Name 1").DataRange.Value)
    vendorNumbers = Application.Transpose(pvt.PivotFields("Vendor Number").DataRange.Value)

    For i = LBound(names) To UBound(names)
        If names(i) <> vbNullString Then
            If dict.exists(names(i)) Then
                dict(names(i)) = vendorNumbers(i)
            Else
                dict.Add names(i), vendorNumbers(i)
            End If
        End If
    Next
    ws.Range("I9").Resize(dict.Count, 1) = Application.Transpose(dict.items)
    ws.Range("J9").Resize(dict.Count, 1) = Application.Transpose(dict.Keys)
End Sub
```

---

Data:

[image]

Comment: Thank you very much QHarr, I tried you method, it works fine... Alternatively by using my method, I have just found the solution, indeed if  instead of this formula in my macro: ActiveCell.FormulaR1C1 = "=VLOOKUP(RC[1],R5C3:C4" & LastRow & ",2,0)" ,I put instead this formula, it works fine also: ActiveCell.Formula = _
        "=IFERROR(VLOOKUP(J5,$C$5:$D" & lastRow & ",2,0),"""")"

Comment: Well done. Posting a question often helps you find the answer yourself:-)